# Format date in specific pattern

Tags: php

I have to format a datetime string in a slightly unorthodox manner - in PHP;

```
2020-09-29T18:36:08.041Z
```

I can come close with;

```
date('c', time()); // 2020-04-19T16:45:08+00:00
```

but my API won't accept it. I've looked through the PHP manual and nothing jumps out at me. Are you able to offer some clues?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call it unorthodox. Z stands for Zero offset. You can just do `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z` but be sure you are using UTC

Comment: Thanks, how would I enforce UTC exactly? `date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.v\Z', time());` It works with your setting. Is UTC a server config then?

Comment: Use gmdate https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Comment: I used `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z', time())` in the end - it appears to hit the db fine without worrying too much about UTC. Thanks.